# Neither command is working at app/console in symfony 2.8

Tags: php, console, symfony-2.8

I'm working on symfony 2.8 project and I'm new in it. Now I try to upgrade it to the newest version. I found the rector package for update the symfony (rector-prefixed exactly, for older version). I've install it and try to run like it is in documentation: https://github.com/rectorphp/rector, and got this error in the console:

```
'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've don't found any information about errors like this so I think it could be a problem connect with console error. When I try to write any command for example:

```
php app/console list
```

I've got this exception back:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\LogicException]
  An option named "connection" already exists.
```

I don't know exactly where to looking for a problem. I will add my console file code and composer.json, maybe someone have same problem as me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// if you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);

set_time_limit(0);

require __DIR__.'/autoload.php';

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(array('--no-debug', '')) && $env !== 'prod';

if ($debug) {
    Debug::enable();
}

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->run($input);
```

```
{
  "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tixi\\": "src/Tixi/"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
  },
  "require": {
    "php": "~7.4",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "apy/breadcrumbtrail-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "composer/ca-bundle": "~1.2.7",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "egulias/email-validator": "~1.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "1.5.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.7.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "1.5.*",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "1.5.*",
    "mediaburst/clockworksms": "2.0.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.5.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "rector/rector-prefixed": "^0.9.31",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
      "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.4"
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "discard-changes": true
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved already the problem. First the problem with Rector was with the command. I don't know exactly why but normal command don't work with my project. In Rector documentation there is:

```
vendor/bin/rector
```

command but in my project there works only:

```
php bin/rector
```

So this problem was solved. Next I have an issue with any other command form command line. There was a Logic exception. But I handle with this after upgrade the Symfony from 2.8 to 3.x. So I think there was conflict between the oldest version of Symfony and the php 7.4 version.